# Does it make sense to calculate MLE for multimodal distributions?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, multimodality

The simplest examples of multimodal distributions I've seen are mixtures, namely mixtures of normals.

However, in this case, the Maximum Likelihood Estimator [MLE] doesn't make much sense. An example is described in the DeGroot and Schervish book.

> The MLE for a mixture of a Normal$(0,1)$ and Normal$(\mu, \sigma^2)$
>   (both parameters unknown) for a sample $(x_1,...,x_n)$ are non-unique:
>   $\hat \mu =x_k$ for $k \in \{1,...,n\}$ and, if we allow it, $\hat
>  \sigma^2=0$.

Are there other examples of multimodal distributions where computing the MLE does make sense?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly doesn't make sense..? You can use algorithms like EM to estimate the ML for a mixture distribution, to give an example. Search yourself for examples: https://www.google.com/search?q=maximum+likelihood+mixture

Comment: @Tim I've added the example from the book.

Comment: I don't get what do you mean by the example and what does your symbols mean.

Comment: I presume that the OP means the likelihood is unbounded for this mixture example.

Comment: @Tim, I hope now it's clearer. Sorry for the inconvenience.